# Battleship Probability Grid

Tags: c++, arrays, nested-loops

I'm trying to make a function for my battleship program to create a probability grid of all the places any of the remaining pieces could be in.  I would like the grid to loop through the entire array, then check if at that point the object has room to be placed (either horizontally, or vertically) and add one to each point it will cover, showing me which coordinates have the best probability of having a ship on them.  BS_GRID_ROWS and BS_GRID_COLS both values holding the size of the battleship board, matrix is the array I would like to display my probability values, and hits is an array with a number (corresponding to each ship) greater than zero if a ship's been hit, -1 if I shot and missed, and zero if the no shot has been made at that coordinate.  Here's the code I have so far.  It's working but not correctly it misses a few squares towards the end completely which I know isn't possible when I run it before any ships have been placed.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

```
void
probabilityGrid(int matrix[BS_GRID_ROWS][BS_GRID_COLS], int hits[BS_GRID_ROWS][BS_GRID_COLS], int shipSize)
{
    bool isValid=true;

   for (int row = 0; row< BS_GRID_ROWS; row++)
   {
       for (int col = 0; (col+shipSize) <BS_GRID_COLS; col++)
       {
           for (int hold = col; hold < shipSize; hold++)
           {
               if (hits[row][hold]!=0)
                isValid=false;
           }
           if (isValid)
           {
               for (int hold = col; hold < shipSize; hold++)
               {
                  matrix[row][hold]++;
               }

           }
           isValid=true;
        }
    }
    //For now I'm just working on the horizontal part of the algorithm.
}
```

Comment: You are likelier to get help if you give more detail on the problems you are having, with examples if possible.

Comment: Right now I'm just trying to cout a picture of the grid with X's for a spot that's not zero, and 0's for a spot that is zero, just for debugging, and it's not hitting a few squares in the bottom of the array at all.  It's missing a bunch at the top right, and I know that if there aren't any boats yet it should hit every square at least once.  Something has to be wrong with my loops.  I couldn't get an example of the array to post on here but it's missing about six in the bottom right corner.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine (or better set and run through debugger) `BS_GRID_ROWS == 1`, `BS_GRID_COLS == 1`, and `shipSize == 1`.

What happens is that the condition `(col+shipSize) <BS_GRID_COLS` is `false` even if `col == 0` which is probably not what you want, and you should change it to `col + shipSize <= BS_GRID_COLS`.

For the same reason, you should change `row<=BS_GRID_ROWS-shipSize-1` to `row + shipSize <= BS_GRID_ROWS`.

Comment: This is definitely right, but I tried it and am still having problems.  It doesn't just skip squares in the bottom, but a few that are boxed in by squares so I don't think its a boundary.

Comment: @GareyFleeman then you should provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with concrete values of constants and parameters. what you get and what the result should be. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)